# mySQL query retrieval question

Tags: mysql

REntal table:

```
CREATE TABLE RENTAL
(
TransactionNo int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
MemberID int NOT NULL, 
ItemNo char(3) NOT NULL,
RentalEmployeeID varchar(30),
ReturnEmployeeID varchar(30), 
Checkout_date DATE, 
Checkin_date DATE,
Return_date DATE,
ItemQuantity int(11) NOT NULL,
TotalPrice DOUBLE(10,2) NOT NULL,
ItemFee DOUBLE(10,2),
PRIMARY KEY(TransactionNo),
FOREIGN KEY(MemberID) REFERENCES Member(MemberID),
FOREIGN KEY(ItemNo) REFERENCES Item(Itemno),
FOREIGN KEY(RENTALEMPLOYEEID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY(RETURNEMPLOYEEID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID)
)
```

I am trying to retrieve the all people who either checked in or checked out something for Joe Smith, however i can't only get the check in or check out and not both. do i need a nested clause?

```
SELECT  r.ItemNo, 
        i.Category, 
        i.Style, 
        i.Description, 
        r.`CheckIn_date`, 
        r.`Checkout_date`, 
        e.Fname, 
        e.Lname   
FROM    MEMBER AS m, 
        ITEM AS i, 
        RENTAL AS r, 
        Employee e 
WHERE   m.MemberID = r.MemberID 
AND     m.Fname = 'Joe’ 
AND     m.Lname=’Smith’ 
AND     r.ItemNo = i.ItemNo 
AND     r.RentalEmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying that records containing both a checkin and checkout aren't selected.  There's nothing about the query preventing that.  It must be that the data is missing such occurrences.

Comment: i'm saying. i have 4 transactions. 2 returns and 2 rentals. 1 employee checked out 2 items and 1 employee checked in 2 items. i am only able to retrieve the rentalemployee by  r.RentalEmployeeID = e.EmployeeID or the returnemployee by r.ReturnEmployeeID = e.EmployeeID

Answer (score 0):

You could replace it with two joins i think...

```
SELECT  r.ItemNo, 
        i.Category, 
        i.Style, 
        i.Description, 
        r.`CheckIn_date`, 
        r.`Checkout_date`, 
        e_rent.Fname, 
        e_rent.Lname,
        e_rtn.Fname,
        e_rtn.Lname  
FROM    ITEM AS i, 
        RENTAL AS r, 
        Member m
LEFT JOIN Employee e_rent ON (r.RentalEmployeeID = e_rent.ID)
LEFT JOIN Employee e_rtn ON (r.RentalEmployeeID = e_rtn.ID)
WHERE   m.MemberID = r.MemberID 
AND     m.Fname = 'Joe’ 
AND     m.Lname=’Smith’ 
AND     r.ItemNo = i.ItemNo
```

Comment: I apprecitae the help. iT appears that I need to do an OR statement with those two selections